# GridView selection cell changes when scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview, android-gridview

I created one GridView that contains 2 columns and multiple rows. The child contains 2 views. If i click on any one child i need to hide 1st view and show 2nd view in that child. this is working fine. But when i scroll the gridview the selected child(ex: child no 2) comes to normal position and another child (random) is appearing like selected. what is the issue. please help me.

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutPlist1"
    android:layout_width="165dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:focusable="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_subCategoryProducts"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <!--
             <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imp" />
        -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_OrPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="₹ 19.80"
                    android:textColor="#ab1b42"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_OrPrice"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="₹ 11.80"
                    android:textColor="#ab1b42"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_productName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="Knorr Cup a Soup Master Masala"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4f"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_productId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_productDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_productCategoryId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_productSubCategoryId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_productStoreId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_productSize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="(16.5 gm)"
            android:textColor="#afafaf"
            android:textSize="7dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_OrPrice1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OR Price : ₹  9.80"
                android:textColor="#ab1b42"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:text="MRP:₹  "
                android:textColor="#4d4d4f"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPValue1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/price_strike"
                android:text="10.00"
                android:textColor="#4d4d4f"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_subCategoryDetails_addToCart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/img_add_to_cart"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutPlist2"
    android:layout_width="165dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#bf1e4a"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:focusable="false" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/plistDetailsRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/details_plist" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close_plist" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/plistBtnRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plistDetailsRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:src="@drawable/leftarrow_plist" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_plist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rightarrow_plist" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pastPurchases_bill_prograssbar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/plistBtnRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plusIconPlist"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/plus_plist" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minusIconPlist"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plusIconPlist"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="23"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/minusIconPlist"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/minus_plist" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MyAdapter:

```
class GridViewAdapterProductList extends BaseAdapter {


    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    Context ctx;
    GridView gv;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    List<EntrySubCategoryDetails>  product;

    public GridViewAdapterProductList(Context context,
            int textViewResourceId, List<EntrySubCategoryDetails> objects,
            ImageLoader imageLoader, GridView gv_subCategoryDetails) {

        mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        ctx = context;
        gv = gv_subCategoryDetails;
        this.product = objects;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

   class ViewHolder {
        NetworkImageView image;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_productName;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_productId;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_productDescription;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_productCategoryId;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_productSubCategoryId;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_productStoreId;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_productSize;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_OrPrice;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPValue;
        TextView tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPTitle; 
        RelativeLayout r1;
        RelativeLayout r2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return product.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return product.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return product.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        ViewHolder holder =null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(
                    R.layout.sub_category_product_list, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_subCategoryProducts);
            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_productId);
            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_productName);
            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productDescription = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_productDescription);
            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productCategoryId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_productCategoryId);
            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productSubCategoryId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_productSubCategoryId);
            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productStoreId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_productStoreId);

            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productSize = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_productSize);
            holder. tv_subCategoryDetails_OrPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_OrPrice);
            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPValue);
            holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPTitle);
            holder. r1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist1);
            holder.r2 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist2);
            view.setTag(holder);
         }else {
                view = (View)convertView;
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                 //ShoppingListNames rowItems = (ShoppingListNames) getItem(position);
            }
       // final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        EntrySubCategoryDetails entry = (EntrySubCategoryDetails) getItem(position);        

        holder.image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.img_loading);
        if (entry.getThumbnailUrl() != null) {
            holder.image.setImageUrl(entry.getThumbnailUrl(), mImageLoader);
        } 
        holder.image.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.img_loading);
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productName.setText(entry.getProductName());
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productSize.setText("("+entry.getProductUnit()+")");
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPValue.setText("₹"+entry.getProductOrMrpPrice());
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_OrPrice.setText("₹"+entry.getProductOrPrice());

        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productId.setText(entry.getProductId()+"");
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productDescription.setText(entry.getProductDescription());
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productCategoryId.setText(entry.getCategoryId());
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productSubCategoryId.setText(entry.getSubCategoryId());
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productStoreId.setText(entry.getStoreId()+"");

        float save = entry.getProductOrMrpPrice()-entry.getProductOrPrice();            
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productName.setTypeface(App_VolleyExamples.tf_roboto_regular);
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_productSize.setTypeface(App_VolleyExamples.tf_roboto_regular);
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_OrPrice.setTypeface(App_VolleyExamples.tf_roboto_medium);
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPValue.setTypeface(App_VolleyExamples.tf_roboto_light);
        holder.tv_subCategoryDetails_MRPTitle.setTypeface(App_VolleyExamples.tf_roboto_light);

        if(product.get(position).isFirstRowSelected())
        {
           holder.r1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           holder.r2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
           holder.r1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           holder.r2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.r1.setTag("first");
        holder.r1.setTag(holder.r1.getId(),position);
        holder.r2.setTag(holder.r2.getId(),position);
        holder.r1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (v.getTag().toString().equals("first")){
                     product.get(position).setFirstRowSelected(true);
                     int indx = (Integer) v.getTag(v.getId()); 
                      View v1=(View) v.getParent(); 
                      RelativeLayout Image=(RelativeLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist2); 
                      Log.i("visible", "first "+v.getVisibility());
                      if(v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                            ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotationY", 0.0f, 90f);
                            animation.setDuration(3600);
                            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                            animation.start();
                            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            ObjectAnimator animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(Image, "rotationY", -90.0f, 0.0f);
                            animation.setDuration(3600);
                            animation1.start();
                            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());  
                            Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      }
                 }      

            }

        });
        holder.r2.setTag("second");
        holder.r2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (v.getTag().toString().equals("second")){
                     product.get(position).setFirstRowSelected(false);
                     int indx = (Integer) v.getTag(v.getId()); 
                      View v1=(View) v.getParent(); 
                      RelativeLayout Image=(RelativeLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist1); 
                      Log.i("visible", "second "+v.getVisibility());
                      if(v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                          ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);
                            animation.setDuration(3600);
                            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                            animation.start();
                              v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              ObjectAnimator animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(Image, "rotationY", -90.0f, 0.0f);
                                animation.setDuration(3600);
                                animation1.start();
                                animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());  
                                Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                      }
                 }                  
            }

        });

        return view;
    }


    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            Mange selected row value in object as defined below.

            Add below things in "EntrySubCategoryDetails" class. 
            private boolean isFirstRowSelected;

            // define getter setter here.
            public boolean getFirstRowSelected()
                {
                    return isFirstRowSelected;
                }

                public void setFirstRowSelected(boolean isFirstRowSelected)
                {
                    this.isFirstRowSelected= isFirstRowSelected;
                }

    In Adapter make below changes.

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getTag().toString().equals("first")){
     product.get(position).setFirstRowSelected(true);
     int indx = (Integer) v.getTag(v.getId()); 
     View v1=(View) v.getParent(); 
     RelativeLayout Image=(RelativeLayout)v1.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist2); 
      Log.i("visible", "first "+v.getVisibility());
      if(v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
       v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                              }

                         }else  if (v.getTag().toString().equals("second")){
                             product.get(position).setFirstRowSelected(false);
                             int indx = (Integer) v.getTag(v.getId()); 
                              View v1=(View) v.getParent(); 
                              RelativeLayout Image=(RelativeLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist1); 
                              Log.i("visible", "second "+v.getVisibility());
                              if(v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                                  v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                  Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                              }
                         }

                    }
  =====================
In getview() add below code.
{
   if(product.get(position).getFirstRowSelected)
  {
     holder.r1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     holder.r2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
  else
  {
     holder.r1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     holder.r2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Urvashi. It solved my issue.

Comment: I added flip animation to hide and show the views in same above code but i am getting same problem.I updated adapter class @Urvashi Hirani

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines

holder.r1.setTag(holder.r1.getId(),position);

holder.r2.setTag(holder.r2.getId(),position);

then the code would be

holder.r1.setTag("first");

holder.r1.setOnClickListener(this);

holder.r2.setTag("second");

holder.r2.setOnClickListener(this);

in onClick function change your code like

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

```
 if (v.getTag().toString().equals("first")) {

   View v1=(View) v.getParent();
   RelativeLayout r1=(RelativeLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist1);
   RelativeLayout r2=(RelativeLayout)v1.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist2);

   if (r1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
       r1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       r2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

 } else if (v.getTag().toString().equals("second")) {

        View v1=(View) v.getParent();
        RelativeLayout r1=(RelativeLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist1);
        RelativeLayout r2=(RelativeLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPlist2);

         if (r2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
             r2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             r1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
```

}